# Is it possible to make a persistent NumPy ndarray interface to multiprocessing Array?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multiprocessing

I need to share common `numpy.ndarray` between multiple processes. It works if the data is packed as `multiprocessing.Array` and converted to `ndarray` just before accessing the array. If I want to wrap the data in `ndarray` once and reuse (the commented-out lines instead of those marked with `# w`), it does not work.

The example works in Python 3.10.4 @Win10 (output below), but if I comment-out the `# w`-lines and uncomment all other, the shared array is not being updated and remains as `[0 0 0 0]` (all 'LOG' output lines show `[0 0 0 0]`).

Question:

- Why the `ndarray` member wrapping `multiprocessing.Array` object in the constructor below is not valid when calling `_update_array` method?

```py
from datetime import datetime
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe, Manager, Array
import numpy as np
import os
import time

curr_time = lambda: datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S-%f")

DATA_TYPE = "i"

class WorkerInterface:
    def __init__(self, data_array, worker_id):
        #self._data_lock = data_array.get_lock()
        #with self._data_lock:
        #    self._data_array = np.ndarray(
        #        (len(data_array),),
        #        dtype="DATA_TYPE,
        #        buffer=data_array.get_obj()
        #    )
        self._data_array = data_array  # w
        self.worker_id = worker_id
        self._keep_running = True
    def _data_as_numpy_array(self):  # w
        return np.ndarray(
            (len(self._data_array),),
            dtype=DATA_TYPE,
            buffer=self._data_array.get_obj()
        )
    @property
    def data_array(self):
        #with self._data_lock:
        #    return self._data_array.copy()
        with self._data_array.get_lock():  # w
            return self._data_as_numpy_array().copy()  # w
    def _update_array(self):
        #with self._data_lock:
        #    self._data_array[self.worker_id] += 1
        with self._data_array:  # w
            self._data_as_numpy_array()[self.worker_id] += 1  # w
    def __call__(self, conn):
        while self._keep_running:
            msg, wait = conn.recv().split(";")
            wait = int(wait)
            time.sleep(wait)
            print(f"W{self.worker_id}, PID {os.getpid()}", end="")
            print(f" @ {curr_time()}>>> {msg} <{wait}s>")
            self._update_array()
            if msg == "stop":
                self._keep_running = False
        conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    NUM_WORKERS = 4
    
    with Manager() as manager:
        
        array = np.zeros((NUM_WORKERS,), dtype=DATA_TYPE)
        shared_array = Array(DATA_TYPE, array)
        
        print("INIT LOG", np.array(shared_array))
        
        workers = []
        for i in range(NUM_WORKERS):
            worker = WorkerInterface(shared_array, i)
            main_conn, worker_conn = Pipe()
            p = Process(target=worker, args=(worker_conn,))
            p.start()
            workers.append({"pipe": main_conn, "pid": p, "worker": worker})
        
        print(f"- C0 @ {curr_time()}")
        workers[0]["pipe"].send("m1;5")
        print(f"- C1 @ {curr_time()}")
        workers[1]["pipe"].send("m2;0")
        print(f"- C2 @ {curr_time()}")
        workers[2]["pipe"].send("m3;3")
        print(f"- C3 @ {curr_time()}")
        workers[0]["pipe"].send("m5;1")
        
        for wi, w in enumerate(workers):
            w["pipe"].send("stop;0")
            print(f"- X{wi} @ {curr_time()}")
            w["pid"].join()
            print(f"- E{wi} @ {curr_time()}")
            print("LOG:", wi, w["worker"].data_array)
            
        print("FINAL LOG", np.array(shared_array))
```

The output:

```
INIT LOG [0 0 0 0]
- C0 @ 11:59:22-764692
- C1 @ 11:59:22-764692
- C2 @ 11:59:22-765694
- C3 @ 11:59:22-765694
- X0 @ 11:59:22-766693
- E0 @ 11:59:29-133874
LOG: 0 [3 1 1 0]
- X1 @ 11:59:29-133874
- E1 @ 11:59:29-153877
LOG: 1 [3 2 1 0]
- X2 @ 11:59:29-154877
- E2 @ 11:59:29-173877
LOG: 2 [3 2 2 0]
- X3 @ 11:59:29-174876
- E3 @ 11:59:29-195878
LOG: 3 [3 2 2 1]
FINAL LOG [3 2 2 1]

W0, PID 3056 @ 11:59:28-092878>>> m1 <5s>
W0, PID 3056 @ 11:59:29-106907>>> m5 <1s>
W0, PID 3056 @ 11:59:29-106907>>> stop <0s>
W1, PID 27116 @ 11:59:23-091694>>> m2 <0s>
W1, PID 27116 @ 11:59:29-133874>>> stop <0s>
W2, PID 19356 @ 11:59:26-095872>>> m3 <3s>
W2, PID 19356 @ 11:59:29-154877>>> stop <0s>
W3, PID 10000 @ 11:59:29-174876>>> stop <0s>
```

Comment: I have tested @Aaron's solution. It works as in his example, but didn't work when placed in my app. I think I get it now: I call Worker's ctor in main thread (`worker = WorkerInterface(...)`) and the NumPy array wraps local Array instance (`self._data_array = np.ndarray(...)`), but then the object is pickled and copied to another Process. The `self._data_array` is just a wrapper around shared data and in the other process it does not have access to the buffer from main process. I just do not understand why there is no error while using the NumPy array `self._data_array` in the other process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My class is intended to be used as worker instantiated in main thread. Then its loop function (`__call__`) is moved to another process. In such case the instance (object) is pickled and send in such form to the another process. There it is unpickled, and the worker loop function of the copy is run.

If the shared array is wrapped in NumPy array in the constructor, the underlying shared array gets broken during pickling and unpickling, so it does not work correctly.

It is important to wrap the shared instance of `multiprocessing.Array` either at the beginning of the processing loop or handle proper wrapping while pickling, by redefining `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods.

A class with working NumPy interface to shared `Array`:

```py
class WorkerInterface:
    def __init__(self, worker_id, data_array, array_shape = None):
        self._raw_data_array = data_array
        self.worker_id = worker_id
        self.shape = array_shape or (len(self._raw_data_array),)
        self.dtype = np.dtype(self._raw_data_array.get_obj()._type_)
        self._wrap_the_array()
        self._keep_running = True
    @property
    def data_array(self):
        with self._raw_data_array.get_lock():
                return self._data_array.copy()    
    def _wrap_the_array(self):
        self._data_array = np.ndarray(
            self.shape,
            dtype=self.dtype,
            buffer=self._raw_data_array.get_obj()
        )
    def __getstate__(self):
        return {
            key: self.__dict__[key]
            for key in self.__dict__.keys()
            if key != "_data_array"
        }
    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.__dict__ = state
        self._wrap_the_array()
    def __call__(self, conn):
        while self._keep_running:
            msg, wait = conn.recv().split(";")
            wait = int(wait)
            time.sleep(wait)
            print(f"W{self.worker_id}, PID {os.getpid()}", end="")
            with self._raw_data_array.get_lock():
                self._data_array[self.worker_id] += wait
                print(f" @ {curr_time()} > {msg} <{wait}s>: {self._data_array}")
            if msg == "stop":
                self._keep_running = False
        conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code example could use a lot of simplification, which might help you find your error, but here's a helper class I use periodically which uses `multiprocessing.shared_memory` (which is internally very similar to `Array`) to share a numpy array, and make it picklable to be sent to and between child processes (you're still responsible for your own locks):

```py
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import shared_memory, Process

class Shared_Arr: #helper class to make shared_memory arrays easier
    def __init__(self, shape, dtype, shm=None):
        self.shape=shape
        self.dtype=dtype

        if shm is None:
            n_bytes = int(np.dtype(dtype).itemsize * np.prod(shape))
            self.shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=n_bytes)
            self.owner = True
        else:
            self.shm = shm
            self.owner = False

        self.close = self.shm.close
        self.unlink = self.shm.unlink

        self.arr = np.ndarray(self.shape, self.dtype, buffer=self.shm.buf)

    def __reduce__(self): #make it picklable so it can be sent to a child process correctly
        return (self.__class__, (self.shape, self.dtype, self.shm))

    def __enter__(self): #context manager is mostly for cleanup so __enter__ is uninteresting
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.close() #closes the memory-mapped file
        if self.owner:
            self.unlink() #tell the OS to delete the file

def populate_arr(shared, value):
    with shared: #without the context manager you could just manually call shared.close() when you're done with it
        shared.arr[:] = value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Shared_Arr([10], int) as shared:
        shared.arr[:] = 0 #np.ndarray may operate like np.empty? initialize to zero
        print(shared.arr) #before modification
        p = Process(target=populate_arr, args=(shared, 5))
        p.start()
        p.join()
        print(shared.arr) #after being modified in a separate process
```